# Carrierwave upload and access file on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am struggling to access files on S3 with Carrierwave.

In my uploader file doc_uploader.rb I have the following code

```
storage :file
def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

to uplooad "doc" model defined as follow

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
mount_uploader :doc, DocUploader
end
```

To access the uploaded file I have the following line of code in a controller

```
@doc = current_user.docs.order("created_at").last #last file uploaded by user
io = open("#{Rails.root}/public" + @doc.doc.url)
```

Everything works perfectly locally. Now I want to move my file to S3 in the uploader I use fog and replace

```
storage :file
```

by

```
storage :fog
```

I adjust my config file carrierwave.rb and **uploading works perfectly**. However, to access the file I try to use

```
@doc = current_user.docs.order("created_at").last
io = open("#{@doc.doc.url}")
```

and I get the following error

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/doc/doc/11/the_uploaded_file.pdf
```

Could anyone give me the right syntax to access the file on S3 please? Thanks.

Comment: I have one question, was the doc record saved before changing the storage to be :fog?

Comment: Yes the doc record was saved.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the asset through the console, it gives you only the path, you might need to append the protocol & host to the `@doc.doc.url`, something like:

```
io = open("http://example.com#{@doc.doc.url}")
```

Or you can set the asset url on the environment you need to, but this is not really necessary:

```
 config.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
```

**This only applies if you are using the console, on any web view this will not apply, carrierwave seems to handle it**